# MongoSpark E11000 error when writing to a MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, replicaset

I am using a **Spark2** application which uses the following command from com.mongodb.spark.MongoSpark to write a DataFrame to a **three-node-MongoDB Replica Set**:

```
    //The real command is similar to this one, depending on options
    //set to the DataFrame and the DataFrameWriter object about MongoDB configurations,
 //such as the writeConcern

    var df: DataFrameWriter[Row] = spark.sql(sql).write
              .option("uri", theUri)
              .option("database", theDatabase)
              .option("collection", theCollection)
              .option("replaceDocument", "false")
              .mode("append")
            [...]    
            MongoSpark.save(df)
```

The fact is that although I am sure the source data, which comes from a Hive table, has a **unique primary key**, when Spark application is running I get a duplicate key error:

```
2019-01-14 13:01:08 ERROR: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 51 in stage 19.0 failed 8 times,
     most recent failure: Lost task 51.7 in stage 19.0 (TID 762, mymachine, executor 21): 
com.mongodb.MongoBulkWriteException: Bulk write operation error on server myserver. 
Write errors: [BulkWriteError{index=0, code=11000,
message='E11000 duplicate key error collection: 
    ddbb.tmp_TABLE_190114125615 index: idx_unique dup key: { : "00120345678" }', details={ }}]. 
at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.getError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:176)
at com.mongodb.connection.BulkWriteBatchCombiner.throwOnError(BulkWriteBatchCombiner.java:205)
[...]
```

I have tried setting **write concern** to "3" or even "majority". Furthermore, the **timeout** has been set to 4/5 seconds, but sometimes this duplicate key error still appears.

I would like to know how to configurate the load in order not to obtain duplicate entries when writing to the Replica Set.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the document coming from which yields the dup key error? Is the `idx_unqiue` applied to the correct field?

Comment: The idx_unique is created over a field which is a compund from four fields in a Hive table: SELECT CONCAT (field_one, field_two, field_three, field_four) AS idUnique. Then, a process to detect duplicates has been implemented, so I am sure, certainly I should be writing unique entries in MongoDB. However, it seems that during the write process a write has been made, and then a retry is performed - the document is already stored in the collection-, so the exception is raised.  And the dependency currently used:     ><groupId>org.mongodb.spark <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11 <version>2.2.5

Comment: I have not seen this error again by using a unique String (e.g. concat the values of the fields of a table's primary key) as the _id of each document